# Retrieve all shortened url created using google

Tags: c#, google-url-shortener

I am working on a project in which i need to create shortened url. I am using google url shortener. Is there any way to retrieve all the urls created using the google account or using the api key

Answer (score 1):

You should use this.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url/history
```

In the headers, set `Authorization` header to `Bearer <authtoken>`

[image]
Make sure you have a valid OAuth Token. Retrieving the Shortened URL History List of a user requires an access token.

You could generate one [here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) for testing it out

Comment: thanks  for your quick reply. it shows error "Login Required" do we need auth if we use api key to get history

Comment: you need to use oAuth token for User's URL history request it seems. edited the answer. :D!

Comment: thanks. but it retrieve  only those url that generated using the UI, can i get the url history which made by using the api key?

Comment: As specified in the URL Shortener API documentation, you need to use the Auth Token to generate the short url in order to make it appear in user dashboard or during retrieval by hitting url/history endpoint. You could generate with an API key but that seems to be missed out when retrieving the user's shortened url history.

Refer this link [Shortening URLs](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten) <---